# Is there a fast way to convert mesh to curves with a very large mesh?

Tags: mesh

At my company, we routinely deal with large meshes that consist of a few hundred thousand interconnected lines. Sometimes, the quantity is greater than a million. On such meshes, the operation of *convert mesh to curve* can be very time consuming, taking 10, 20, 30, on up to >60 minutes. Is this to be expected? Are there any suggestions about ways to accelerate the operation? Finally, is there any simple explanation for why a seemingly simple operation would consume so much CPU time?

Comment: Convert to Mesh will work on multiple selections at once. The only issue, then, might be the process of making the actual selections. I don't know what kind of structure your mesh might have, so I can't comment further.

Comment: Usually if something is unexpectedly slow (i.e. other programs do it faster) it comes down to Blender being an all-in-one solution.  When you make a change to anything there's a lot of different data to recalculate.